# Как добвить html в переводы в nuxt?

Tags: vue.js

Хочу в переводы на `nuxt-i18n` добавить некие `html` теги. Но на сайте выглядит все так же как в строке. Например `Now you need to&nbsp;confirm <br> email` выглядит на странице так(см. картинку). В документации не нашел как это исправить.
[image: пример работы кода на странице]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так там обычный vueJS добавляйте не через `{}` а через `v-html`

```
<div v-html="news.text"></div>
```

Comment: ```<p v-html="$t('index.open_account')"></p>``` да. так сработало